# Any way to get to the Recent Activity info from my profile?

Tags: support, recent-activity, profile-page

I would love to get access to the info from /users/recent/id (specifically, where I'm getting my rep from) but I can't find it linked anywhere from my /users/id page.

Comment: I would answer this but I'm sure it's a dupe and I don't have the energy for freehand circles on a Monday morning.  Oh crap, it's afternoon now...  So I guess, click on your username at the top of the screen, then click the Reputation tab underneath your profile info.

Answer (score 3):

Click on the little envelope next to your username at the top of the screen.

[image: where the envelope is]

You'll find tabs that will give you a breakdown of what other people are doing with your stuff (up/downvoting you, responding to your posts) etc.

If you click on your username itself, you can see a breakdown of what *you* are doing: your questions and answers, your own comments and edits, etc. There is also a nice pretty graph showing how your reputation is going up over time. :)

Comment: Jason! Very subtle, random ;)

Comment: I have not found this and I am a user for about a year. Maybe this should be more prominent and also linked with a real descriptive caption in the user profile?